# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Estou com problema ao fazer um insert na base utilizando PDO.
O PHP me apresenta esse erro. Pesquisando, vi que esse erro se refere que a quantidade de parametros não batem nos bindValues, por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha) VALUES (:nome, :email);
```

Ou então:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, email, senha) VALUES (:nome, :email, senha);
```

Mas ja revirei todo meu código e nao acho o erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Segue codigo:

```
$stmt = $conn->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO
        usuarios (
            nome,
            email,
            senha,
            saldo_dindone,
            datacria,
            horacria, 
            status,
            foto_perfil,
            ativacao,
            hash_ativacao,
            facebook_id
        ) VALUES (
            :nome,
            :email,
            :senha,
            :saldo,
            :datacria,
            :horacria,
            :status,
            :foto_perfil,
            :ativacao,
            :hash_ativacao,
            :facebook_id
        )");
```

E os bindValue:

```
    $stmt->bindValue(':nome', $fbfullname);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindValue(':senha', $seg_senha);
    $stmt->bindValue(':saldo', $saldo_inicial);
    $stmt->bindValue(':datacria', $data);
    $stmt->bindValue(':horacria', $hora);
    $stmt->bindValue(':status', 'pendentedados');
    $stmt->bindValue(':foto_perfil', $foto);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ativacao:', 1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':hash_ativacao', '0');
    $stmt->bindValue(':facebook_id', $fbid);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Desde já agradeço!

#### EDIT

rray
Sei que aqui no SO já tem tópico com este tipo de erro. Mas se tivesse lido meu tópico teria visto que eu procurei o problema e identifiquei o porque estava dando erro no meu código, mas não conseguia achar qual era a linha que estava errada no meu código!

Comment: Sua consulta tem `:ativacao` seu bind está `:ativacao:` tem um `:` sobrando no final.

Comment: Nossa, era isso mesmo. Funcionou aqui. Valeu!